# jQuery daterangepicker shows year as 0 or -1

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am having a very strange problem with daterangepicker.

I load all the necessary `JavaScript` files before the `</body>` tag.

Here are the js files:

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/members/js/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/members/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/members/js/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/members/js/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/members/js/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/members/js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/members/js/icheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/members/js/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/members/js/app/app.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#reservation1').daterangepicker({
      singleDatePicker: true,
      showDropdowns: true,
      dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });
    $('#reservation2').daterangepicker({
      singleDatePicker: true,
      showDropdowns: true,
      dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });
    $('#reservation3').daterangepicker({
      singleDatePicker: true,
      showDropdowns: true,
      dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    });
</script>
```

and then i get this:

[image][image]

Shouldn't it display the current date? and shouldn't i be able to choose some years?

Any help will be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Where did the "daterangepicker" code come from? There are dozens of date widgets out there.

Comment: if you mean the js file it comes straight from http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: OK yes I found that; I just wasn't sure it was the same one. Well it looks to me as if it's initializing with a weird start and end date (like, the end date is the year 0).

Comment: the date field in the database has by default this value 0000-00-00 so maybe this is why. But when i load the data from db it loads this value to the field if previously not set. Is there a way so that i can change this?

Comment: The documentation for the date range thing says there are "start" and "end" configuration parameters.